# Save Excel sheet as html file similar to manual save as

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiple sheet Excel workbook. I want to save one sheet as a html file using VBA.

It should be like the save as operation. When doing a manual save as the formatting is displaying in the saved HTML file. When using VBA the formatting is lost.

```
Application.Sheets("MNM Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\Reports\09192014\mnm.html"
```

How to do this functionality with out losing the formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `FileFormat` argument of the `Workbook.SaveAs` Method. E.g.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\Reports\09192014\mnm.html" FileFormat:=xlHtml
```

You can see more options for `FileFormat` in the  [XlFileFormat Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff198017(v=office.14).aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: Yeah I got this and when try to run the macro html file is created along with some support files like style sheets.And just want to know when I try to do save as manual there are no style sheet files but now I am getting and manual save file looks little good compared to the file generated by macro.

Comment: Note: Need to add comma in front of the `FileFormat:=xlHtml` statement. Without this, there would be a compile error.  `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\Reports\09192014\mnm.html", FileFormat:=xlHtml`